# Changing letter spacing in terminal VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hello everyone recently I started to use Monokai for VSCode but my terminal is also customized. I also changed my font family to Verdana (it was the default). But my VSCode terminal changed weirdly like this:

[image]

I felt like letter-spacing is too much and tried to lower it down a bit in the settings.json file but It gets weird.

Can anyone overcome a problem like this or can I still use my default terminal customization?